# How to convert smallint of t-sql to integer in c#?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

I'm having problems converting smallint in t-sql to integer in C#.

Please can someone help me with a way round this?

Update #1

What i really trying to do is retrieve data from a column marked as smallint in sqlserver 2005 from a datareader into my application. Im sorry i'll was not really clear enough previously.

Comment: What problems do you have? Can you give an example?

Comment: Given that there are several different approaches to fetching data from SQL Server, you're giving us very little to go on.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Not quite sure what problems you are having as the range of numbers in smallint is a subset of the range of integer values.

The standard convert in c# should work:

```
int intFromSmallInt = Convert.ToInt16(smallint);
```

Is the error coming from an ORM?

Comment: I was trying to retrieve it from a SqlDataReader object. This is what i did finally. dr.GetInt16(dr.GetOrdinal("ColumnName")). Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 13):

There is also the C# DataType "**short**", which is System.Int16 (a.k.a. "**smallint**" in SQL Server).

I prefer to use "short" just because I think it looks cooler and for no other reason.

Also, I'd use the following to pull your data (if it is nullable):

```
short? sVal = dr["ColName"] is System.DBNull ? null : (short?)(dr["ColName"]);
```

Comment: _"I prefer to use "short" just because I think it looks cooler"_ a valid reason is: because it's the correct type when you choose `smallint`. If you'd use `int` you'd allow numbers that are too large to be inserted into database.

Comment: I prefer the "short" datatype over the structure "System.Int16".  Int16 is a Structure that aliases short.  You are fine using either one.  I did not mean I preferred short over int - that would obviously be wrong.

Answer (score -3):

```
int? value = (int?)(row["ColumnName"] as short?);
```

Comment: Just minus? Can explain why?